# PHP MySQL return divided result

Tags: php, mysql, divide

I have query:

```
SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY ( firstColumn / anotherColumn ) DESC
```

Now I'm printing this:

```
return $query['firstColumn'] / $query['anotherColumn'];
```

Is it possible to print divided result without any php tricks? For example `return $query['dividedColumns'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column Alias will solve your problem, you can change your query to:

```
SELECT members.*, 
      ( firstColumn / anotherColumn ) AS `divided_amount`  
FROM members 
ORDER BY divived_amount DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly in the query, and use that result as the `ORDER BY` argument too.

```
SELECT *, firstColumn/anotherColumn as dividedColumns 
FROM members 
ORDER BY dividedColumns DESC
```

Now you can use it as `$query['dividedColumns']` in PHP.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT *, (firstColumn/anotherColumn) AS dividedColumns FROM members ORDER BY ( firstColumn / anotherColumn ) DESC
```